# Getting 404 error when viewing CakePHP 3 app on 1and1

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp-3.0

When I attempt to hit my site which is at `mydomain.com/subfolder`, I get a 404 (from Apache).

`/subfolder/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

`/subfolder/webroot/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

To confirm that `mod_rewrite` works, I added this in the `/subfolder/.htaccess` file which promptly redirected:

```
Redirect 301 / http://other-domain-owned.com/
```

So, `.htaccess` are live and `mod_rewrite` works.

On my development environment, I was able to make the site work in the same `/subfolder` by symply enabling `.htaccess` files for that folder via a `Directory` directive.

Some tutorials say to add `RewriteBase /` but this didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `RewriteBase`, you can also use an absolute path. Additionally, the first two rules can be simplified to one

```
RewritRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Similar the second part

```
RewriteRule ^ /subfolder/webroot/index.php [L]
```

Finally, [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) are from different modules. So, if one of the directives is working, this is no proof for the other one working too.